# Apache Shiro: Permission filter is validating last matched path

Tags: google-app-engine, guice, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro with Guice on Google App Engine.

Following filter chain is present in configureShiroWeb() function

```
addFilterChain("/**/first/second/third/**", AUTHC_BASIC, config(REST, "X"));
addFilterChain("/**/first/**", AUTHC_BASIC, config(REST, "Y"));
```

When a request is made for an API- example.appspot.com/v1/first/second/third, the first filter is bypassed and the access is granted for a user with permission Y and not with X.

I am using the following shiro and guice related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-guice</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Shiro, If you are still running into this issue let us know.

Comment: I have upgraded the Shiro version to 1.4.0-RC2, then also the issue persists.

Comment: Try the latest official 1.3.2 release, if you still run into a problem we will get a fix in for the next release

Comment: I am still facing the issue even after using 1.3.2 release.

Comment: Sorry @Shilpi, I should have checked but this sounded familiar, it should be resolved by: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=shiro.git;a=commit;h=53001435a9908d1a59b506043f71fc237ab2cb04 if you want to try it out.   I originally thought this was related to new work from the 1.4.0 branch

it should be resolved in the next release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-605

Comment: When will 1.4.0 version be released?

Comment: In the next couple of days!

Comment: I tried Shiro 1.4.0 and Guice 4.0. But the error is still present.

The ShiroWebModule class is creating a randomly ordered path to config map in filterToPathToConfig, because it's using a HashMap instead of a LinkedHashMap.

The offending line is here:
https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/support/guice/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/guice/web/ShiroWebModule.java #L161

This should be a LinkedHashMap to maintain original user order.

Comment: Thanks for the pull request!